# Desktop Bridge App Communication with out of process background Task

Tags: uwp, background-task, desktop-bridge

How to communicate and launch desktop bridge app from out of process background task?

Comment: I have my background task out of process registered, and my desktop bridge acts as App Service which works as in process background task. How do i communicate between them and pass data between them?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Start with the context you're working in: environment, os, precisely what you're trying to do, some code, what you expected to happen, what actually happened.

Comment: @xyzWty First of all, normally your app service will be registered as a separate background process and you will need to convert it to in process service if it is required. So why you are converting it to a in process background task? So like smurtagh mentioned we need to konw why you are doing this. For me personally I think you might not doing the right thing when design your app.

Comment: I have implemented solution similar to given in this sample link - https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/NorthwindSample

Now, my app has time trigger background task, from that background task i want to send and recieve data from .exe application, from background task(ie out of process - added as WinRT project). How do i Achieve this? @BarryWang-MSFT

Comment: I am using Background task Time Triggered type, which is separate from desktop bridge solution.

Comment: @xyzWty You cannot lauch another app from backgroundtask. As the UWP scope method launchuriasync can only be called from UI thread.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync) And there is no doc shows that backgroundtask can talk to exe app directly(here we ignore the network part). If you want to have a timer when reading data, try build the timer in your desktop app. Then use it to call the app service to get the data at a specific time. I believe that will be better.

Comment: @xyzWty By the way, do you actually mean that you want to have a backgrountask to working with Sql Server to log some data every period of time? In that way, what about use Sql Server agent to directly do this and save the data to a file. Then you can just handle the return data from that file from your app. Would this make sense for you?

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT No, I want to send mails emails from outlook apis in my Background Task(Time Triggered), for sending outlook mails I am using Desktop Bridge solution provided my Microsoft in UWP.

Answer (score 0):

To launch a full trust process (desktop-bridge process) from a UWP background task use the [FullTrustProcessLauncher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher) API.

Comment: How to communicate with desktop-bridge process from UWP background process, two-way communication between background task and desktop bridge process?? I implemented that solution but, after launching desktop-bridge process how do i maintain connection using AppService??

Comment: Do you mean communicating back to the UWP app process, or the TimeTrigger background task? I assume you want to communicate with the app itself, since the background is short-lived by nature (gets cancelled after 30sec). A tutorial for how to communicate with the app via AppServices can be found here: https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/   You can also use AppServices to communicate with the background task, but this would require an extra step and I am not sure I understand the scenario for wanting to do that.

Comment: I meant communicating back to Time Trigger background task, In order to extend background task time I have used, 
<rescap:Capability Name="extendedBackgroundTaskTime" />
<rescap:Capability Name="extendedExecutionUnconstrained" /> 
in my Application.How to use AppService to communicate with Out of Process Background Task?

Comment: The easiest way will be to make the TimeTrigger background task in-proc. This way it will run in the same process as the UWP app, and you can then communicate with it from the desktop bridge process in the same way you currently communicate to the UWP app. If that's not an option you will have to do two-step communication, going from desktop bridge process to UWP app process to background task process.

Comment: Can you show some steps or application workflow how tow step communication will work? TimeTrigger background task in-proc is not an option to me.

Comment: I don't have a sample handy at the moment, but the gist is that you connect from both the desktop-bridge process and the background-task process to the AppService of your UWP app. In the app you hold on to the two AppServiceConnection instances separately and when you receive a request on one instance you forward it to the other, and vice-versa.